# Dual wielding magic items vs spell components

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting, spell-components

Say, we have a caster (e.g., wizard or warlock) who is holing a (distinct) magic item in each of their hands (arcane grimmoire or rod of the pact keeper in one hand, and wand of the war mage in the other hand). If one of these items acts as a spellcasting focus, they can perform most of their spells without problems, but as far as I understand, they cannot use spells which have a somatic but no material component. Is this correct?

If so, what can they do to resolve this issue? Would the Warcaster feat help them in this case to cast spells like Shield which have a somatic but no material component?

Comment: It looks like the Q&A Matthieu found is addressing your issue: a non-weapon magic item in each hand, and trying to cast a spell without material components using the War Caster feat. Let us know why it would not help, if you thinks it does not.